# An Euclidean geometry question with circles.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, geometric-transformation

This question is from exercise 1.15 of "Geometry: Euclid and Beyond".

Let two circles $\gamma$ and $\delta$ meet at a point $P$. Let the tangent to $\gamma$ at $P$ meet $\delta$ again at $B$, and let the tangent to $\delta$ at $P$ meet $\gamma$ again at $A$. Let $\theta$ be the circle through $A, B, P$. Let the tangent to $\theta$ at $P$ meet $\gamma$ and $\delta$ at $C, D$. Prove that $ PC \cong PD $.

Hint: Draw lines joining $P$ and the centres of the three circles, and look for a parallelogram.

[image: picture]

My thought:

I have followed the hint and found the parallelogram the hint refers to. I can complete the question if I can prove it is indeed a parallelogram. But I don't see a way to prove it.

Can someone good at geometry help me out?

**Edit**:

I added a hand-drawn picture to illustrate my idea. In the picture, the centres of the three circles are $O_1, O_2, O_3$. So the parallelogram the hint refers to is $PO_1O_3O_2$. I don't know how to prove this is a parallelogram, but if I can prove it, I can then show that $\triangle O_1CO_3 \cong \triangle O_2DO_3$ by $SAS$ congruence. Then I'm able to show that $\triangle O_3CP \cong \triangle O_3DP$, hence solve the problem.

Can some one help to show why the quadrilateral $PO_1O_3O_2$ is a parallelogram?

[image: hand drawn picture]

Comment: Why do I get downvotes?

Comment: Because you recited the question verbatim to us without showing any effort in doing it.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @A---B That was a misunderstanding. I did try working on it. I will update the question to show my thoughts.

Comment: @RuiLiu I will change my vote when you update your question.

Comment: @A---B Done. Please help me with the question if you're good at geometry.

Comment: @Théophile The question is to prove PC is congruent to PD, which is in the second paragraph.

Comment: @RuiLiu Yes, I read the problem description; I wanted to know what *your* question was. Thank you for adding your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Inversion solution**

Make an inversion at $P$ with arbitrary radius $r$. Then Circle $\theta$ maps to line $\ell$ which is parallel to its tangent. Then images $A'$ and $B'$ of $A$ and $B$ lies on $\ell$. Similary $\varepsilon$ maps to line $a$ which is parallel to line $PB$ and $\delta $. So $A'$  and image $C'$ of $C$ lies on $a$. Since $C'$ lies on $CD$ and $B'$ lies on $PB$ we see that $A'B'PC$ is parallelogram. So $C'P = A'B'$

In the same way we deduce that $D'P=A'B'$ so $p$ halves $C'D'$ and thus it halves also $CD$.

**Synthetic solution**

Because of angle between tangent and a chord we have $$\angle ACP = \angle APB = \angle PDB = :\alpha$$ Similary we have $$\angle APC = \angle ABP =:\beta \;\;\;\;{\rm and}\;\;\;\;\angle BAP = \angle BPD =: \gamma$$
Since $\alpha +\beta+\gamma = 180^{\circ}$ (see angles at $P$) we have
$$\triangle ACP \sim  \triangle  APB \sim \triangle PDB$$
so we have
$${CP\over BP} = {AP\over AB} \;\;\;\;{\rm and}\;\;\;\;{DP\over AP} = {BP\over AB}$$
and thus $$ CP = {AP\cdot BP\over AB} = DP$$

Comment: Is it possible to have a solution using only triangle congruence?

Comment: I don't believe. I searched for some congruence but I don't see it, since there is nothing congruent from the staring data.

Comment: I added another picture to show my idea. Would you like to have a look at that?

Comment: Yes, it is OK, since $PO_2\bot PA$ and $O_1O_3\bot PA$ you have $PO_2||O_1O_3$. The same is for $PO_1||O_2O_3$, so $PO_1O_3O_2$ is paralelogram. Great done!

Comment: Where do you get $O_1O_3 \perp PA$?

Comment: Oh! I got it! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Well, $O_1$ is on perpendicular bisector of secant $PA$